# Calling a specific UserControl based on which node is checked in a TreeView structure

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, eventhandler, treeviewitem

In my Windows Form, there are two User Controls, placed one on top of the other.

I also have a TreeView Structure (TreeView1) that has a root node (with two child nodes itself, with check boxes).

Basically, I wish to make only one User Control visible when the Tree View Node corresponding to that User Control is checked.

This is the code that I've written to respond to the checking event:

```
private void TreeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
      string Case;

      Case = e.Node.Name;

      switch (Case)
      {
        case "Call_UC1": //Name of the first node of TreeView Structure
             UC1.BringToFront(); //UC1 - object of the User Control 1
             UC1.Visible = true;
             break;

         case "Call_UC2": //Name of the second node TreeView Structure
             UC2.BringToFront(); //UC2 - object of the User Control 2
             UC2.Visible = true;
             break;

         default:
             break;
       }
    }
```

Problem is, the User Controls are not responding when I check any of the check boxes of either node. Nothing is happening. I'm guessing that my implementation of the TreeView Event Handler was not proper. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean with *User Controls are not responding*? `BringToFront()` doesn''t seem to have any effect? Some of their components is not responsive? Are the UCs disabled, by chance? Btw, you can just `switch (e.Node.Name)` and `UC2.Visible = true;` dosn't look like it's useful, since the UCs are one on top of the other.

Comment: 'Not responding' in the sense, that the top most User Control(UC2)  is the only one that is visible, even if I check the node for making UC1 visible. UC2 is on top, as per the way I designed my Form. So basically on running the form, it is showing only the TreeView and UC2, and doesn't change even on checking the other node. If I place UC1 on top in the design of my form, on running the form UC1 is what appears, and sticks around even after checking the other box.

Comment: With he code you have here and the one Idle_Mind posted, if the UserControls don't switch places or nothing happens, then you have to check whether the event handler is actually wired or the names are a match: `Call_UC1` etc. Note that the comparison is case sensitive.

Comment: Okay,I actually changed the code a bit, and made the UCs respond to Selection, instead of Checking. And it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

AfterCheck() also fires when a node is **UNCHECKED**...you need to check for this.  Also, do you have code in place that prevents **both** of the boxes from being checked at the same time?  Otherwise, which one should be in front?  Whatever one was last checked?

...and what happens if both are not checked after previously having been checked?  Should the UserControls be invisible?

So many questions...

This ~might~ be what you're after:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Checked)
        {
            if(e.Node.Name == "Call_UC1")
            {
                UC1.Visible = true;
                UC1.BringToFront();
            }
            else if (e.Node.Name == "Call_UC2")
            {
                UC2.Visible = true;
                UC2.BringToFront();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Damn. I gotta admit, I didn't give these points a lot of thought. My lack of experience shows...Thanks a lot for bringing these to my attention. And yeah, maybe a part of the problem must be that I didn't account for the 'Unchecking' aspect.